# Changing working directory to current in netrw

Tags: netrw

My working directory is `/a` and I open up netrw with `:tabe /b`. I now want to change my working directory  to `/b`. I read that `:cd<CR>` should work but it just does the same thing as typing `cd` in a buffer (sends me home).

Using netrw v171 and VIM 9.0.749.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
cd %
```

which I interpret as: vim thinks that current dir is open file so `cd %` changes to open dir in netrw.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked in VIM9, but I still don't get why. :help % linked me to some usage of % seemingly unrelated to this answer (•_•)

Comment: I also use vim9. `%` is the register where the current filename is. In input `Ctrl-r %` writes current filename. Also, `:echo expand('%')` echos current filename (and current path in netrw) so I guess `cd %` expands to `cd current_path` in netrw.